# Why does a vapor "hello" project crush right after start on Sierra?

Tags: macos-sierra, vapor, dyld

I'm trying to run vapor hello project via terminal. Didn't touch any code.

Building is ok, but it doesn't run.

Already tried

- clean and rebuild
- force reinstall vapor
- check that libsqlite3.dylib is loaded

Here's terminal output:

```
MacBook-Air-Dmitrij:Hello dev$ vapor run
Running Hello ...
[ INFO ] Migrating 'sqlite' database (/Users/dev/Hello/.build/checkouts/fluent.git-6251908308727715749/Sources/Fluent/Migration/MigrationConfig.swift:69)
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _sqlite3_column_table_name
  Referenced from: /Users/dev/Hello/.build/debug/Run
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _sqlite3_column_table_name
  Referenced from: /Users/dev/Hello/.build/debug/Run
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
```

Do you have any idea, what's going on?

- MacOS 10.12.6
- Swift 4.1.3
- Xcode 9.3
- Vapor Toolbox: 3.1.10
- Vapor Framework: 3.3.1

Comment: Vapor3 is almost deprecated cause Vapor4 will be releazed soon. It'd be better to install Catalina and Vapor4 and start from that point.

Comment: @imike, thanks for the answer. My MacBook 2011 doesn't support Catalina :(

Comment: A "technically feasible", but non-trivial, path to Vapor4 on a older system is [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) + Ubuntu 18 + [Swift 5.1](https://swift.org/). I use both the VirtualBox+UbuntuServer+Swift and VirtualBox+UbuntuDesktop+Swift combinations in addition to the macOS Swift Package Manager & Xcode toolchains. The VB combinations have been useful when developing a light weight embedded web for an [ARM-based kitchen IoT devices project ÓSK Squirrel](https://hackaday.io/project/165563-sk-squirrel). … [github](https://github.com/opensmartkitchen) :-)